# How can I refresh a angularjs directive every x seconds?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

How can I refresh a angularjs directive every x seconds ? I want to reload function attached to link ever x seconds, regards.

Comment: Is it your own directive or 3rd party? And what do you mean by refresh? Full re-initialization?

Comment: Please be more descriptive with your question. Include an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use an interval in your directive. But remember to destroy the interval when the directive is destroyed:

```
angular.directive('myDirective', myDirective);

myDirective.$inject = ['$interval'];

function myDirective($interval) {
  var i = undefined;

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope) {
      i = $interval(function () {
        // Do stuff here.
      }, seconds * 1000);

      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        console.log("destroy");
        if (angular.isDefined(i)) {
          $interval.cancel(i);
          i = undefined;
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```